# How to use dynamic URL in Apigee Service Callout

Tags: apigee, callout, dynamic-url

This is a easy one.I need the `<URL>` element in the Apigee Service callout(SC) as dynamic one.

Eg: `<URL>http://{dynamicURL}</URL>`

Where `dynamicURL` will be determined at runtime and this value will be different for every request. It will have the complete target URL such as (ip:port/abc/orderid/1234)

```
<HTTPTargetConnection>
<Properties />
<URL>http://{dynamicURL}</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Have tried these:

- In a JS policy, tried setting `servicecallout.{scpolicyname}.target.url` in the context. In this case only the dynamic `ip:port` is getting sent. The URI is missing `/abc/orderid/1234`.
- In the `AssignMessage` policy, created a header and tried using it in SC URL element like request.header.name, {request.header.name}, with $ at front.
- In the `AssignMessage` policy, created a variable & tried using it in SC like `{dynamicURL}` with `$` at front.

This is a common usecase and I'm sure there must be a easy way to do. Need your help with this.

Thanks,

Somu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the ServiceCallout and AssignMessage policy.

You can set the `ip:port` in the ServiceCallout policy itself.  Set this in the element `<URL>http://{dynamicURL}</URL>` of the `<HTTPTargetConnection>`, just as you noted.

As for the rest of the URI, you can use the AssignMessage policy `<Path>` element.  Here is an example:

```
<AssignMessage enabled="true" continueOnError="false" async="false" name="GenerateAuthorizationPayload">
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="true" type="request"/>
    <Set>
    <Payload contentType="text/xml">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="urn:sample">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <v1:Login/>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </Payload>
    <Path>/abc/orderid/1234</Path>
    <Verb>POST</Verb>
    </Set>
</AssignMessage>
```

You should also be able to put a `{variable}` inside of the `<Path>` tags if you need flexibility there.

It is the combination of these 2 policies that you get a dynamic `ip:port/path`.

Comment: I should add that in the latest released of OPDK, you can add <path> in the actual callout itself.  No need for a separate AssignMessage step prior.  Also, the <path> in the callout allows variables.  The <path> in AssignMessage does not translate variables.

Comment: For example: `<ServiceCallout async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="CalloutBAASConfig">
    <DisplayName>CalloutBAASConfig</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Request variable="BAASCalloutRequest"/>
    <Response>BAAScalloutResponse</Response>
    <HTTPTargetConnection>
        <Properties/>
      <URL>http://{_BAAS_IP}/1234/{dealerId}</URL>
    </HTTPTargetConnection>
</ServiceCallout>`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using target servers. It's cleaner and they're specifically designed for the purpose you just described. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702740/apigee-modify-target-path-when-using-targetserver/24704056#24704056).

Comment: Thanks for your input, thats a good idea. In my case, the IP:port will change for every request. Given a request, the ip & URI contents are mapped. So routing to LB wont work if gets picked by other servers in LB instead of specific one. But I like this implementation as its clean & just found out that we are already using this for a different use case :)